# Unexpected Values Returned (MAX(id))

Tags: php, mysql, echo

Code Used(db connection already established):

```
<?php 
$cur = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM trades");
echo "$cur";
while($cur >= 0) {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trades WHERE id='$cur'");

if(mysql_num_rows($query)==0) {
    echo "ERROR!";
    exit();
}
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

$tradeID = $row['ID'];
$mcUsername = $row['Minecraft Username'];
$blockID = $row['Block ID'];
$quantity = $row['Quantity'];
$costPer = $row['CostPer'];
$tradeNotes = $row['TradeNotes'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='first-td'>$tradeID</td>";
    echo "<td>$mcUsername</td>";
    echo "<td>$blockID</td>";
    echo "<td>$quantity</td>";
    echo "<td>$costPer</td>";
    echo "<td class='last-td'>$tradeNotes</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $cur = "$cur - 1";
} 
?>
```

The echo of the $cur is returning : `Resource id #7`

And the if statement is returning `ERROR`, which is most likely caused due to $cur not working right.

Is there some kind of syntax error in what I'm doing because when I run the SQL query for $cur manually in MySQL DB it returns the expected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM trades");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
$cur = $row[0];
echo "$cur";
```

`mysql_query` returns a resource for select query not a value. [Check what is returned by mysql_query and notice the warning against using mysql_ function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: Okay, I've changed the code to use this. My problem now is that, the page just sits there loading. Nothing is echo'ed and the page is not reloaded. I'm assuming it's stuck in the while loop. Do you notice any other errors in my code?

Comment: check the last part `$cur = $cur - 1`. You have it quoted. Remove the quote probably in an infinite loop

Comment: Thanks! I assumed it was stuck it a loop, but am still a little rough around the edges when it comes to PHP syntax. Thanks, it appears to be working now!